# Can I use a gradient with border-color?

Tags: html, css, border, gradient

I am trying to set `border-bottom` property with a gradient color to my `DIV` element.

My expecting output should be something similar to this.

[image]

So can anybody tell me Can I reach to this without using an image and only using pure CSS?

This is how I tried it

```
.border-gradient {
    border-width: 0 0 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-image: 
        -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 0, 0 0, from(#53001e), to(rgba(152, 31, 74, 0))) 100% 1;
    -webkit-border-image: 
        -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #53001e, rgba(152, 31, 74, 0)) 100% 1;
    -o-border-image:
             -o-linear-gradient(left, #53001e, rgba((152, 31, 74, 0)) 100% 1;
    -moz-border-image:
           -moz-linear-gradient(left, #53001e, rgba((152, 31, 74, 0)) 100% 1;   
}
```

But can not get it to work 100%.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HsTcf/187/)

Any ideas would be greatly welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your image looks like the color decreases the hue then increase from left to right. Unfortunately, CSS won't be able to do this at the moment. It can only increase or decrease the hue at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
.border-gradient {
    background: rgba(92,7,52,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(92,7,52,1) 0%, rgba(134,29,84,1) 12%, rgba(255,93,177,1) 47%, rgba(83,0,30,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(92,7,52,1)), color-stop(12%, rgba(134,29,84,1)), color-stop(47%, rgba(255,93,177,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(83,0,30,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(92,7,52,1) 0%, rgba(134,29,84,1) 12%, rgba(255,93,177,1) 47%, rgba(83,0,30,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(92,7,52,1) 0%, rgba(134,29,84,1) 12%, rgba(255,93,177,1) 47%, rgba(83,0,30,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(92,7,52,1) 0%, rgba(134,29,84,1) 12%, rgba(255,93,177,1) 47%, rgba(83,0,30,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(92,7,52,1) 0%, rgba(134,29,84,1) 12%, rgba(255,93,177,1) 47%, rgba(83,0,30,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5c0734', endColorstr='#53001e', GradientType=1 );
}
```